# Remove files, which provided by pipe

Tags: shell, find, text-processing, xargs

I have this command chain:

```
find . -print | grep php | xargs grep 'eval' -sl | xargs wc -l | grep ' [1-2][0-9] '
```

This provide me this output:

```
 14 ./includes/js/calendar/lang/vgju.php
 18 ./includes/phpInputFilter/default.php
 14 ./includes/Archive/eula.php
 18 ./media/system/js/json.php
```

This files are infected php files and I would like to remove it with my chain.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Although you can probably do this whole thing with find command only you can try appending `|xargs rm -f` to that command.

Here's what it would look like

```
find . -print | grep php | xargs grep 'eval' -sl | \
    xargs wc -l | grep ' [1-2][0-9] ' | \
    cut -f 2 -d ' ' | xargs rm -f
```

Note that the `xargs rm` command works here because you know there aren't any special characters in the file names. If there might be spaces in the file names, you can use `xargs -d '\n' rm -f` (Linux only).

Comment: This wont work, because there is the line numbers in the output of my command. Is there some substring command wherewith I could split the lines after the line number?

Comment: @Roland add cut -f2 -d' ' to the pipeline right before the suggested xargs

Comment: try xargs -n1 rm -f

Comment: Thanks for both of your. Luis solution worked. Now I get the full list with this funny command: find . -print | grep php | xargs grep 'eval' -sl | xargs wc -l | grep ' [1-2][0-9] ' | xargs -n1 | grep 'php'